# Does the expectation of any bounded function on Gaussian variables exist?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, gaussian-integral

I want to prove the expectation of the function $f(X)$ exists, where $X$ is a Gaussian variable. Given that $f(X)$ is bounded between $[-c, c]$, with $c$ being some positive constant, does the expectation of $E[f(x)]$ always exist?

I think it exists because
$$E[f(x)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-(x-\mu)^2}/(2\sigma^2),$$
and since $-c\leq f(x)\leq c$ for any $x$,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty -c\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-(x-\mu)^2}/(2\sigma^2)\leq E[f(x)]\leq\int_{-\infty}^\infty c\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-(x-\mu)^2}/(2\sigma^2).$$
Those two integrations are bounded so $E[f(x)]$ is bounded. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't think it matters that $X$ is Gaussian. If the random variable $Y$ takes values in $[-c, c]$, then the expectation $E[Y]$ will also be in $[-c, c]$. This is true if $Y=f(X)$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \to [-c, c]$, regardless of what $X$ is.

Comment: Thanks, @angryavian! That makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me. By this same reasoning you can say $-c \leq E\{ f(x) \} \leq c$, which is even stronger.